# Rich snippet error: "Price, review or availability needs to be present" But it is

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm having problems inserting Rich Snippet code for a product. I literally copied it from some Google page and edited it to my product. The Google Webmaster's Rich Snippet tool gives the error:

> In order to generate a preview with rich snippets, either price or
>   review or availability needs to be present.

But it does have the data about price: [image: "Offerdetails: Item 2 (...) Item 2 property price: ..."]

So, will Google still be able to find the price given for the product in the snippets? Or is the error real?

The code is used:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product"><span itemprop="brand">Ten Cate</span> <span itemprop="name">Katoensatijnen dekbedovertrek</span><a href="http://reclameblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/satijn.png"><img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-41880" alt="ten cate katoensatijnen dekbedovertrek" src="http://reclameblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/satijn-300x199.png" width="300" height="199" /></a>&nbsp;Beoordeling: <span itemprop="rating" style="color: #00ad00;">4.5</span><span itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">Normale prijs: €49.95 Vandaag voor:<meta itemprop="currency" content="EUR" />€<span itemprop="price">24.99</span>Aanbieding loopt tot <time itemprop="priceValidUntil" datetime="2014-05-19">19 mei 2014!</time><span itemprop="availability">Vandaag nog verkrijgbaar!</span></span></div>
```

Comment: Be careful with Google examples regarding rich snippets. Much of their examples and advice is faulty. I suspect that this is because these pages were written before the code to parse rich snippets. I use the schema.org examples most though they have gotten even more confusing lately. I have not parsed your code, but the most common mistake I have seen here is nesting elements in types appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, Google's examples are often incorrect. Generally the examples from Schema.org are correct and instructive, though their breadcrumb navigation syntax is a notable exception (Google's is correct for that).

If you go to http://schema.org/Product and run the first example code through the Stuctured Data Testing Tool, you'll see that it functions correctly.